# how to setinterval with websockets in PHP

Tags: php, websocket

I am working on Php with websocket(Ratchet),I have multiple Post Time(dynamic),And i want to update every minute like (1 min ago,1 hour ago etc )
So can we do with use of websocket or is this possible only with jquery "set interval function" ? How can we do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.